Hit a snag whilst adding a subclass to std::vector
My idea was initially to create my own custom vector with methods built in for various mathematical calculations, as well as the usual std::vector features, for the sake of regression analysis. I decided it made more sense to expand the std::vector library with a subclass, which will inherit the std::vector features whilst having those mathematical methods as well.
I decided to create two new vectors, one for each data set used with methods for averaging, summing, and so on, and these vectors are to be inserted into the second vector which calculates the correlation coefficient, p-value, and other things which require two or more data sets.
In the process, I got this error message for the declaration of the vector in the global scope:

'child_vector' in 'class std::vector' does not name a template type

and I get this error in main():

'thing' was not declared in this scope

Placing the declaration into main() instead brings this error message:

'child_vector' is not a member of 'std::vector'

Adding <T> to the end of class child_vector yields this error message:

child_vector is not a template type

Noting out the declaration and the std::cout lines causes the error messages to disappear.
The code is:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace std
{
    template <typename T>
    class child_vector : public vector <T>
    {
        public:
        // things go here   
    };
    
    template <typename T>   
    class parent_vector : public vector <T>
    {
        public:
        // things go here   
};  }       // namespace std

int main()
{
    std::vector <float>::child_vector <float> thing = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::cout << thing[1] << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}

This is the first time I have attempted something like this involving classes, and searching Google finds few results which address this error message in this situation. I am using g++23 on a Windows system.
As I also see this effort as a learning experience, any kind of input will be appreciated.

The container classes from namespace std rarely are supposed to be inherited. Looks like a xy-problem. What are you actually trying to do?

A better design is having global statistical functions accepting std::vector arguments.

std::vector doesn't have a virtual destructor so you shouldn't subclass it.  Plus adding stuff to the std namespace is not allowed.  And std::vector takes more than one template argument - it has T and also an Allocator.

When using OOP and inheritance, ask yourself: is there an is-a relationship between these two things, and if so, does there need to be?

Standard classes are not meant to be inherited from. And you can't legally add new classes to the std namespace, only specializations of existing standard templates. If  you want a class design, you should use Encapsulation instead of Inheritance.
In any case, in your main(), your declaration of thing is using the wrong type. std::vector <float>::child_vector <float> should be simply child_vector <float>, as child_vector is its own type that derives from std::vector, it is not a nested member type of std::vector itself.
child_vector <float> thing = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

